# vba code to save documents by specific name

Tags: excel, vba

I have salary slip of 800 assoicates which i can get only in asingle document. Each time o have to save salary slip one by one at a time. I need vba code that can save salary slip by thier name. Following code i tried but no result.

```
Sub BreakOnPage()
Dim my_filename As String
Dim ss As String
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by page.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage

   For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")


      'Select and copy the text to the clipboard.
      ss = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("asam").Range.Text
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy


      ' Open new document to paste the content of the clipboard into.
      Documents.Add
      Selection.Paste
' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the page, if any.
      Selection.TypeBackspace
      Selection.TypeBackspace
       Selection.TypeBackspace
      ChangeFileOpenDirectory "E:\raju"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=5
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Copy
    my_filename = Selection
      ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Namevariable & ss & ".doc"
      ActiveDocument.Close

      ' Move the selection to the next page in the document.
      Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) I think you have used the wrong tag; This looks like "word-vba" which is very different from "excel-vba".  (2) (2) Did you mean to use an extension of "doc"?  The extension "doc" was last used with Word 2003.